# Return false on click event not working

Tags: jquery, click, return, anchor, preventdefault

Any idea why this code is not working? I've spend one hour searching and testing for something that was supposed to be ridicule simple! I have tried with return false and other solutions suggested in other answers but the page still jumps to the top ignoring return false. What's wrong?

```
$('#about a').click(function(e) {
    $('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.95);
    $('#about-text').fadeTo(300, 1);
    e.preventDefault();   
});
```

**EDIT:** This is the html for the #about a. Maybe there is something wrong in the syntax of the element in the script?

```
<div class="projects" id="about"><a href="#">About</a></div>
```

**EDIT 2:** After extensive searching, trial and error i couldn't find why this didn;t work. I decided to remove the # anchor link from #about div and apply he function directly on the div which of course works without problem since it has no href anymore.

Comment: Either make a jsfiddle for it, or save yourself the trouble and debug it with firebug.

Comment: What browser are you using? Everything seems to be working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxv5Y/

Comment: Try putting `e.preventDefault()` at the top as the first item in the function.

Comment: Look at your HTML structure and ensure everything's right according to your script, in this case, placing `e.preventDefault()` is not the issue, take a loot at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/b9qYp/1/) example.

Comment: Yes, as everyone has already demonstrated, putting `preventDefault()` at the top may be good practice, but it clearly should work even at the bottom.  Without seeing your HTML, or your demo, we cannot reproduce what you describe.  Nothing to do.

Comment: @MK_Dev I'm testing this in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Mac. All ignoring  return false; or preventDefault();.

Comment: I think there might be a problem in the script with the syntax of the element to be clicked. I posted the HTML for this div.

Comment: We've asked you several times to setup a jsFiddle or a demo page.  [Your code, exactly as you've posted it, works perfectly fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/b9qYp/1/)  Something else is causing the result you see.

Comment: @Sparky672 All suggestions were pointing to the right direction and it was all helpful to narrow down the possible causes of the unexpected result. I didn't setup a jsFiddle due to the complexity of my html php js code it wouldn't help. So i just focused on this specific part and decided to skip the href finally. This is without doubt an extraordinary narrow situation:)

Comment: SO questions are not meant solely as personal troubleshooting assistance to the OP... they must also be helpful to other readers.  Without posting a demo and since there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, how is this question is ever going to be relevant or helpful to anyone else?  That's why it was closed.

Comment: @Sparky672 You are absolutely right! I didn't say the opposite and i wasn't requesting for personal assistance. It just turned out to be more complicated than i first thought due to the nature of my code and it wouldn't be helpful for others to try fitting it in a jsFiddle. I completely agree with the closing of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#about a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('.overlay').fadeTo(300, 0.95);
    $('#about-text').fadeTo(300, 1);
     return false;
});
```

Placing e.preventDefault() at the top will ensure the event is stopped. You might have a runtime error with your fadeTo functions.

Comment: return false would actually never be reached if there is a runtime error in the fadeTo above as well.

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. The page still goes to the top. I even replaced both fadeTo actions with css events. But still no change.